# Martingale difference sequence - is the sum a martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am reading the wikipedia page on martingale difference sequences. $X_n$ is a martingale difference sequence with respect to a filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ if it is adapted, integrable, and $E[X_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=0$.

In particular it says that if $Y_n$ is a martingale, then $X_n=Y_n-Y_{n-1}$ is a MDS. It does not make any mention of the converse. Is the converse true?

I think it is, because $Y_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} X_k$, so that $E[Y_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]= Y_{n-1}+E[X_n\mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]=Y_{n-1}$.

PS: I know wikipedia isn't the best source. Could someone confirm whether or not I am correct?

Comment: It seems correct; but check integrability condition too.

Comment: Is this not trivial since each $X_n$ is integrable?

Comment: It is trivial but you should mention it always.

Comment: Why $E[Y_n|F_{n-1}] = Y_{n-1} + E[X_n|F_{n-1}]$? How did you get $Y_{n-1}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why MDS $X_k$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957302/why-mds-x-k-is-measurable-with-respect-to-mathcal-f-k)